# What is the preferred deployment strategy for configuration files in PHP

Tags: php, file, deployment, config

When deploying a web application in PHP, one doesn't always want your configuration files with passwords to be committed into the repository.

What is the preferred method of handling this, ie.

- saving the details in a DB, and templating the config file
- copying the file onto the server (which raises the question of where to save 
  and version the file being copied in)
- setting the environment variables on the server, and having the config file reading from
  that.

or any other suggestions.

Comment: Personally, i commit the config file without passwords and usernames. Then i add it to ignore list so it won't be commited once it's configured. My config files usually include only passwords, login and so on. The rest is more public, like settings.class.php

Comment: I've recently been favoring the config implemented by Laravel: http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#protecting-sensitive-configuration

Answer (score 0):

You can have your config files in a folder out of the public folder and restrict the access to that folder using `.htaccess` file. Of course this works if you are using Apache as webserver.

Comment: This question is more based on how to get the file there, than where the file should be.

Comment: ah, my apologies, in that case you have few options. If you are using a version control such as git, you can clone it on the server side, other option is using http://capistranorb.com/ as deployment strategy, you can also use rsync command. Also you can adopt http://www.yaml.org/ files for configuration as Symfony does. Hope this helps

Comment: sure, but how do you keep your configuration file out of the repository - most often you don't want your sensitive info being in a repo.

Comment: Assuming you are using git, add them to '.gitignore' file. git will not keep track of them at all and won't push them to repository. Then use `scp` to securly copy them to your server. Just keep in mind you won't have change track on these files from git.